# Alphabet sorting script returns no output (Python)

Tags: python

I am new to programming so cut me some slack. I apologise in advance for asking such a dumb question and thank you for your time.

What I'm trying to do:
I want to make a program that converts letters with their position in the alphabet. I am finding the position of X character by searching it's index in a list (where I have put the alphabet) with a while loop. When all the characters are converted I presumably print the result in a string. But it doesn't have any output when I run it. It doesn't show any errors or warnings so I'm completely lost on what the problem might be.

Why is that and how do I resolve this issue?

Again, thanks for your patiance with me.
Here's the code:

```
    def alphabet_position(text):
    alphabet_pos = []
    result = ""
    index_1 = len(text)
    i = 0
    while i < index_1:
        list_pos = index_1 - 1
        character = text[list_pos]
        if character.isdigit:
            pass
        else:
            alphabet_low = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
            alphabet_cap = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                            'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
            if character in alphabet_low is True:
                alphabet_pos.append(alphabet_low.index(character))
            elif character in alphabet_cap is True:
                alphabet_pos.append(alphabet_cap.index(character))
            else:
                pass
        i += 1
    for char in alphabet_pos:
        result = str(alphabet_pos[char]) + " "
        char += 1
    print(result)
alphabet_position("hello")
```

Comment: You don't call `alphabet_position()` anywhere

Comment: You do not need "if character in alphabet_low is True:" just "if character in alphabet_low:"

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk I only posted the function and I had called it in my code. I should have put it there too probably. Sorry about that. I will edit that real quick.

Comment: @Stenly Gonzalo Odiard, is right, `character in alphabet_low is True:` will always be False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many things to unpack in your code.

First of all, `if character.isdigit:` should be replaced with `if character.isdigit():` . `if character.isdigit:` basically asks whether `isdigit` function is defined and will always return `True`.

Next, you don't need `character in alphabet_low is True`, `character in alphabet_low` is enough.

Next, you don't really use `i` anywhere and `character` variable would still be the same letter. Also, you don't need while loop, you can just iterate over the letters of the `text`.

Next, I don't really understand what you want to do in the last 3 lines before `print(result)` so I just rewrote it the way I would do it.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```py
def alphabet_position(text):
    alphabet_pos = []
    result = ""
    alphabet_low = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    alphabet_cap = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    
    for character in text:
        if not character.isdigit():
            if character in alphabet_low:
                alphabet_pos.append(alphabet_low.index(character))
            elif character in alphabet_cap:
                alphabet_pos.append(alphabet_cap.index(character))
    for char in alphabet_pos:
        result += str(char) + " "
    print('result:', result)
```

I suggest when you write code, use `print` statements more often to see how what you've written so far works.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, I was struggling on this for hours!

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can accept it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ). Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve it like this:

```
ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
dct = {y: x for x, y in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}

def alphabet_position(text):
    return [dct[char.lower()] for char in text if char != ' ']

alphabet_position('some text')
# Out[61]: [18, 14, 12, 4, 19, 4, 23, 19]
```